# As3 with SoundCloud API - Player

Tags: actionscript-3, api, soundcloud

Hi I need some info about the API in as3 language. I am making a flash app, and loading succesfuly the soundcloud player. But when I have to change the song or reopen the same song, it keeps throwing the same null error at `com.soundcloud.player.audio::AudioController/progressHandler()`

I think I just need to reset the "player" but I don't want to urlrequest the player again.

The only API controls from as3 I know for are the events. 
Need the play, reset, pause properties controls.